# How to insert next max value using insert select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a two tables. I want to insert table1 data into table2 if records from table1 are not present in the table2.

I can do this. main problem with my query.

```
 create table #Customer
(
    ID int,
    Name nvarchar(20),
    Email nvarchar(20)
)

create table #Customer2
(
    ID int,
    Name nvarchar(20),
    Email nvarchar(20),
    Value varchar(20)
)

insert into #Customer values (1,'AAA','A@mail.com')
insert into #Customer values (2,'BBB','B@mail.com')
insert into #Customer values (3,'CCC','C@mail.com')
insert into #Customer values (4,'DDD','D@mail.com')
insert into #Customer values (5,'EEE','E@mail.com')
insert into #Customer values (6,'FFF','F@mail.com')
insert into #Customer values (7,'GGG','G@mail.com')


insert into #Customer2 values (3,'x','asa@mail.com','10001')
insert into #Customer2 values (6,'y','B@mail.com','10002')
insert into #Customer2 values (8,'z','z@mail.com','10003')



update C2
set C2.Email = C1.Email, C2.Name = C1.Name 
from  #Customer C1
inner join #Customer2 C2  on C2.ID = C1.ID

insert into #Customer2 
select C1.ID, C1.Name, C1.Email, (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(int, Value))+1 from #Customer2
) from  #Customer C1
left join #Customer2 C2 on C2.ID = C1.ID
where C2.ID is null


select ID,value  from #Customer2

drop table #Customer
drop table #Customer2
```

The result is

id  value

3   10001

6   10002

8   10003

1   10004

2   10004

4   10004

5   10004

7   10004

I want it as

id  value

3   10001

6   10002

8   10003

1   10004

2   10005

4   10006

5   10007

7   10008

Please advice!

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: I have one confusion, in first statement you said have to insert records from table1 to table2 if not present in table2.
Then what is the Value column second table ?

Comment: There will be some records already exist. Check in example 10001 through 10003. now whatever new records going to inserted should have value greater than previous max value i.e. 10004.

Comment: Why can't we create identity for that column if it is auto increment.

Comment: Exactly, column is used everywhere and we want to achieve it without marking it as identity column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Row_Number` starting with the maximum value in `Customer1` table to generate the ID's in customer 2 and the except operator to insert the data which is not present:

```
INSERT INTO #Customer2(ID,Name,Email,Value)
select ID,name,email, (SELECT MAX(value) from #customer2) + row_number() over (order by id) value 
from (select ID,Name,email from #Customer
except SELECT ID,name,email from #Customer2)ValueForInserting
```

Comment: That's wonderful! Thanks a lot AJJ. Thanks a lot ram.bi for your time and advice.